# Source manager vs Backups

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, svn, team-foundation-server

I need to get input of some it proffessional.

My point is, when you have developpement, example, web developpement and you get some .cs files, aspx files, .css , .js and you get somme graphic files like .psd etc ...

What is the best solutions to backup all your developpement.

A server files, in raid your backup every day, or a source manager of all source files.

I think if you put all your developpement in a source manager, like subversion or TFS, it's the best way to work. You could backup your source manager DATABASE on the server, and with a source manager you win Historique modification of your files.You only have to backup the source manager database and if a trouble occurs, your just restore the database.

If your are in RAID and the RAID fails, and your backups files is corrupt, you will maybe lost some files and never get historical modification of your file

What did you think about this solutions, every people get 1 TB disk on here computer to get the file from source manager, and the server backup will just backup the database of the source manager.

Every body know in IT worlds, they always have someting more important and urgent that check if the backup file was working correctly and we are never cover of an incident on a server file vs One server files, with 5 disk of 1 TB and only some files are on the source manager.

What is your opinion about that ?

Answer (score 4):

First:

- -RAID is not Backup.
- -Revision/Source Control is not Backup.
- -Backup is not Revision/Source Control.

Of these, only RAID is optional, but just barely.

You should be using Revision/Source Control for any code repositories that you have, even if you are the only developer and don't expect it to change much.  It's recommended that you have your disks on at least a RAID 1, RAID 1+0 (sometimes called RAID 10) or RAID 5 array.  I prefer RAID 6.  RAID 0 is asking for heartache.

If a disk has failed, that takes precedence over everything except a fire in the building.  Priority #1 is to replace the disk.  If your server is under warranty (such as a HP, Dell, IBM, etc), put in a ticket to the vendor stating that you need a replacement disk.  As soon as it arrives, your new immediate first priority is to actually put it in the server and if necessary start the Array Rebuild.

You need to back up your Source Control repository.  It may be worthwhile to also copy it occasionally to a separate copy (such as burning to a DVD periodically.)

Finally, you need to test your backups.  After it completes successfully, attempt to restore it to another box.  If it doesn't work, you don't have a backup.  After you get this working, look up (Tape) Rotation Strategies.  After a disk or server has failed is not the time to test your backups.

Comment: +1 for the bullets. All key things that people get confused over. If you've a good source control solution it's important to have everything in it, not just code repositories.  I've seen people lose a lot time as they didn't think to include things like DB scripts, image files, documentation in the version control along with the code.

Comment: +1 for source control document not just code.

Comment: Ditto.  I meant to make that point but you beat me to it.